# AWS CDK StateMachine BatchSubmitJob with dynamic environment variables

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-step-functions, aws-batch

I'm trying to create a statemachine with a BatchSubmitJob in AWS CDK with dynamic environment variables in the BatchContainerOverrides. I was thinking about something like this:

```
container_overrides = sfn_tasks.BatchContainerOverrides(
    environment={
        "TEST.$": "$.dynamic_from_payload"
    }
)

return sfn_tasks.BatchSubmitJob(self.scope,
                                id="id",
                                job_name="name",
                                job_definition_arn="arn",
                                job_queue_arn="arn",
                                container_overrides=container_overrides,
                                payload=sfn.TaskInput.from_object({
                                    "dynamic_from_payload.$": "$.input.some_variable"
                                }))
```

However, upon deployment, CDK will add "Name" and "Value" to the statemachine definition, but Value is now static. This is part of the statemachine definition as seen in the console:

```
"Environment": [
    {
        "Name": "TEST.$",
        "Value": "$.dynamic_from_payload"
    }
]
```

But I need to have it like this:

```
"Environment": [
    {
        "Name": "TEST",
        "Value.$": "$.dynamic_from_payload"
    }
]
```

I also tried using "Ref::", as done here for the command parameters: [AWS Step and Batch Dynamic Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942824/aws-step-and-batch-dynamic-command). But this doesn't work either.

I also looked into escape hatches, overwriting the CloudFormation template. But I don't think that is applicable here, since the generated statemachine definition string is basically one large string.

I can think of two solutions, both of which don't make me happy: override the statemachine definition string with escape hatches with a copy in which "Value" is replaced on certain conditions (probably with regex) OR put a lambda in the statemachine that will create and trigger the batch job and a lambda that will poll if the job is finished.

Long story short: Does anyone have an idea of how to use dynamic environment variables with a BatchSubmitJob in CDK?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions/JsonPath.html) class:

```
container_overrides = sfn_tasks.BatchContainerOverrides(
    environment={
        "TEST": sfn.JsonPath.string_at("$.dynamic_from_payload")
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks!

I ended up with a Pass state with intrinsic functions to format the value and the aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath for the BatchSubmitJob.

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to [K. Galens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70067059/16554649)!

I ended up with a Pass state with [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) to format the value and the [aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions/JsonPath.html) for the BatchSubmitJob.

So something like this:

```
sfn.Pass(scope
    id="id",
    result_path="$.result",
    parameters={"dynamic_from_payload.$": "States.Format('static_sub_part/{}',$.dynamic_sub_part)"} )

...

container_overrides = sfn_tasks.BatchContainerOverrides(
    environment={
        "TEST": sfn.JsonPath.string_at("$.result.dynamic_from_payload")
    }
)
```